# Sql-Filter the Select

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
SELECT DISTINCT x1.NUM_KANBAN_ID ID, 
                TO_CHAR(x1.DT_CREATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') CREATED,
                x5.TXT_PLANT_CD CD,
                TO_CHAR(x4.DT_FIRST_VIEWED,'YYYY-MM-DD') VIEWED,
                TO_CHAR(x4.DT_DUE,'YYYY-MM-DD') DUE, x4.
                TXT_SHUTTLE_NUMBER SHUTTLE, 
                (select count(*) 
                 from WEDI_ASN_TO_DIMENSION t8 
                 where t8.TXT_MATCH_CD='1' 
                 AND t8.NUM_DIMENSION_ID=x2.NUM_DIMENSION_ID AND t8.NUM_MATCH_ID = x1.NUM_KANBAN_ID) ASN, 
                 x1.TXT_JIT_CALL_NUM,
                 x2.NUM_VENDOR_ID VENDOR_ID 
 FROM WEDI_KANBAN x1, WEDI_DIMENSION x2, WEDI_USER_VENDORS x3, WEDI_KANBAN_TO_DIMENSION x4, WEDI_PLANT x5
 WHERE x5.NUM_PLANT_ID = x2.NUM_PLANT_ID AND 
       x1.TXT_STATUS_CD = 'C' AND
       x2.NUM_VENDOR_ID = x3.NUM_VENDOR_ID AND 
       x4.NUM_DIMENSION_ID = x2.NUM_DIMENSION_ID AND 
       x1.NUM_KANBAN_ID = x4.NUM_KANBAN_ID AND 
       x1.DT_CREATE < SYSDATE - 15 AND
       x5.TXT_PLANT_CD LIKE '%'  AND
       x2.TXT_MATERIAL_NUM LIKE '%' AND 
       ((x4.TXT_SHUTTLE_NUMBER IS NULL) OR (x4.TXT_SHUTTLE_NUMBER LIKE '%')) AND 
       x4.DT_DUE < SYSDATE - 10 
 ORDER BY VENDOR_ID
```

In the above query i should display the id's whose ASN is only 1 or 2 . If the ASN has like this 0,1,2 i Should not display those IDs. Generally if the id's ASN has 0 i should not display.
Pls suggest

Comment: eeerrrrrrrrrrrrr..... Which field holds the ASN?

Comment: hihi, is the subselect in the `select` clause :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is:

```
select * 
from (your query)
where 0 not in (select ASN from (your query))
```

In order to not write the query twice:

```
with (your query) as A
select * 
from a 
where 0 not in (select asn from a)
```

or

```
with (your query) as A
select * 
from a 
where not exists (select * from a where asn = 0)
```

However, exists the posibility to rewrite your query to return no rows when exists an ASN equal to zero, but the query is hard to understand, and almost sure something is wrong because you need a DISTINCT clause. That's bad sign.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like `(ASN = 1) Or (ASN = 2)` in your Where statement